# How to use a regular expression to parse a text file and write the result on another file in Java

Tags: java, file-io

I used a regular expression to parse a text file to use the resulted group one and two as follows:

- write group two in another file
- make its name to be group one

Unfortunately, No data is written on the file!
I did not figure out where is the problem, here is my code:

```
package javaapplication5;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.regex.*;

   public class JavaApplication5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here


          try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/End-End-Delay.txt");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            File newFile1= new File("C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/AUV1.txt");

            FileOutputStream fos1= new FileOutputStream(newFile1);
            BufferedWriter bw1= new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos1));


            String strLine;

            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("sender\\sid:\\s(\\d+).*?End-End\\sDelay:(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)");
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);

                    while (m.find()) {

                        String b = m.group(1);
                        String c = m.group(2);

                         int i = Integer.valueOf(b);
                         if(i==0){

                         System.out.println(b);

                         bw1.write(c);

                        bw1.newLine();

                         }

                        System.out.println(b);
                       // System.out.println(c);


                    }

            }
        } 
            catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }




    }

}
```

Can anyone here help me to solve this problem and Identify it?

Comment: We cannot, at least not without details of the file you're reading.

Comment: Your code will only write to file if `m.find()` is `true` **and** `i==0` , is that actually the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using BufferedWriter, and never flush (flushing writer pushes the contents on disk) your writer or even close it at the end of your program.

Due to which, before your content gets written in actual file on disk from BufferedWriter, the program exits and the contents get lost.

To avoid this, either you can call flush just after writing contents in bw1,

```
bw1.write(c);
bw1.newLine();
bw1.flush();
```

OR

Before your program ends, you should call,

```
bw1.close(); // this ensures all content in buffered writer gets push to disk before jvm exists
```

Calling flush every time you write the data is not really recommended, as it defeats the purpose of buffered writing.

So best is to close the buffered writer object. You can do it in two ways,

1. Try-with-resources
2. Manually close the buffered writer object in the end, likely in the finally block so as to ensure it gets called.

Besides all this, you need to ensure that your regex matches and your condition,

```
if(i==0){
```

gets executed else code that is writing data in file won't get executed and of course in that case no write will happen in file.

Also, it is strongly recommended to close any of the resources you open like file resources, database (Connection, Statements, ResultSets) resources etc.

Hope that helps.